# Get upload progress for Cloudinary Unsigned Upload

Tags: cloudinary

I'm doing an unsigned upload from the browser straight to Cloudinary and am trying to display progress for large uploads.

I'm using the [cloudinary node library](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#unsigned_upload).

Is there any way to get the upload progress using the cloudinary library in the browser, or is there another way to upload directly to cloudinary that would give me progress?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @MuhammadUsamaMashkoor I solved it by sidestepping cloudinary's library. Posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by uploading through a XHR request rather than relying on cloudinary's library:

```
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('upload_preset', CLOUDINARY_MEDIA_PRESET);
    formData.append("file", file); 

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
      if(xhr.readyState !== 4) {
        return;
      }
      if(xhr.status !== 200) {
        // Handle request errors
        return;
      }
      let res = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      if(!res || !res.public_id) {
        // Handle cloudinary errors
        return;
      }
      // Handle success
    };

    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", e => {
      // Handle progress with Math.round((e.loaded * 100.0) / e.total)
    });

    xhr.open("post", `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${CLOUDINARY_CLOUD}/auto/upload`);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

    xhr.send(formData);
```

Answer (score -1):

Indeed this can be done using the relevant jQuery events, as described here:
http://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520672-How-to-create-an-upload-progress-bar-

You can also check out the sample project in Node: https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm/blob/b101e3bda667dac307c08bca3084538921f45fec/samples/photo_album/views/photos/add_direct.ejs#L70

Comment: I'm not using jquery right now, but I'll give it a look. Thanks.